# Automator bash shell script trouble

Tags: bash, shell, audio, ffmpeg, automator

I'm probably missing something really simple here, but I'm have trouble building an automator service that runs a bash shell script. All of the elements of the script work fine when plugged into shell, but for some reason the automator service is failing to run. The script calls ffmpeg to convert an audio file passed to it from the finder:

```html
for f in "$@"
do
  fn="${f%%.*}"
  ~/Applications/ffmpeg/ffmpeg -i "$f" -acodec libmp3lame -q:a 7 -ar 8000 -ac 1 "$fn.mp3"
done
```

The script runs fine without the ffmpeg command, and the ffmpeg command runs fine in the terminal on its own. Where's the error coming from?

Thanks!

Comment: Show what the script is trying to execute with `set -x`, `echo "f=$f, fn=$fn" or `echo ~/Applications/ffmpeg/ffmpeg -i "$f" -acodec libmp3lame -q:a 7 -ar 8000 -ac 1 "$fn.mp3"`

Comment: Thanks for the help, @WalterA. After messing with it for far too long it ended up being some difference in how terminal and automator are handling the variable strings. While the command executes fine in terminal, I needed to add brackets around the fn variable in automator. 

~/Applications/ffmpeg/ffmpeg -i "$f" -acodec libmp3lame -q:a 7 -ar 8000 -ac 1 "${fn}.mp3"

runs just fine.

Answer (score 0):

it ended up being some difference in how terminal and automator are handling the variable strings. While the command executes fine in terminal, I needed to add brackets around the fn variable in automator.

```
~/Applications/ffmpeg/ffmpeg -i "$f" -acodec libmp3lame -q:a 7 -ar 8000 -ac 1 "${fn}.mp3"
```

runs just fine.